# How to put a variable in the codeigniter temaplate

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I have a view:

```
public function index()
{

    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    if ($lang == "fr"){
        $this->smarty->display('excel.tpl');    
    }
    else{
        $this->smarty->display('excel_eng.tpl');
    }
}
```

My template:

```
<div class="fullscreen background" id="landing-page-image">
    {include 'components/menu.tpl'}
</div>
```

I want to replace a component depending on the language

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this :

**excel.tpl :**

```
<div class="fullscreen background" id="landing-page-image">
    {include 'components/menu.tpl'}
</div>
```

**excel_eng.tpl :**

```
<div class="fullscreen background" id="landing-page-image">
    {include 'components/menu_eng.tpl'}
</div>
```

EDIT

**PHP code :**

```
...

$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

$smarty->assign('lang' , $lang); // passing lang to templates

....
```

**HTML code :**

```
<div class="fullscreen background" id="landing-page-image">
    {include 'components/menu_$lang.tpl'}
</div>
```

Comment: How to put variable in {include 'components/variable here'}??

Comment: Why passing a var when your are using different templates from the beginning ?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** The first option here is to load language variables and have common template for them:

```
$lang = 'en';//your default language
$available_langs = array('en', 'fr'); //your set of languages
$browser_lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
if (in_array($browser_lang, $available_langs)) {
   $lang = $browser_lang; //set language according to browser
}
//assumed you keep your language variables in /app/language/lang_en.php
require_once(APPPATH.'language/lang_'.$lang.'.php');
$this->smarty->assign('lang_vars', $lang_vars);
```

example of lang_en.php:

```
<?php
$lang_vars = array(
'some_var_1'=>'Some string',
'some_var_2'=>'Another string',
);
```

Example how to use in .tpl file:

```
<div>
{$lang_vars.some_var_1}
</div>
```

**2.** The other option here is to load different templates based on same approach when you have detected language:

```
...
$this->smarty->display('some_template_'.$lang.'.tpl');
```

But that's considered bad practice, cause you need to support and change 2 sets of templates.